# How do I duplicate a cell based on the first character?

Tags: excel

I have a column in Excel that contains two ID numbers, one of which starts with an A and the other which is all numbers.  I want to split these values into two columns based on what character they start with, either a number or the letter A.  I'm basically looking for an If statement that says if the first character of a cell is "A", then copy it into another column, if this is possible.  Thanks.

[image]

This is how I will want the table to look, only copying over the values that begin with A into the next column.

Comment: I am sure it is possible, but a mock up of your data and expected outcome would help us help you.

Comment: The left function will be a good staring point for your issue

Comment: A few more informations would be helpful. e.g. some example data to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in C2:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,1)="A",B2,"")
```

And copy/drag down.